# Sorting collapsed collections in Laravel/Lumen Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm trying to collapse (join together) Laravel collections from 3 different queries, and then sort them by the same key 'recordTime'.
Because the queries are each accessing different tables, I'm not sure if there is a way to use orderBy like a regular query.
Here is my code so far:

```
 $books = $targetItem->books()->whereBetween('recordTime', [$from, $to])->get();
 $magazines = $targetItem->magazines()->whereBetween('recordTime', [$from, $to])->get();
 $articles = $targetItem->articles()->whereBetween('recordTime', [$from, $to])->get();

 $collection = collect([$books, $magazines, $articles]);
 $collapsed = $collection->collapse();
 //$collapsed = $collapsed->sortBy("recordID");
 $records = $collapsed->all();
```

$targetItem is a model with a hasMany relationship to each books, magazines, and articles.

I seem to successfully collapse the collections, which results in an array of objects. However when I try to use the [sortBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-sortby) function (commented out above) it targets the objects, rather that the keys within the objects.

Sorry if I'm using the wrong terminology, but I basically need it to sort by one level down.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
Output without the sortBy line

```
"data": [
    {
        "recordID": 1,
        ...
    },
    {
        "recordID": 2,
        ...
    },
```

Output with the sortBy line

```
"data": {
    "0": {
        "recordID": 1,
        ...
    },
    "1": {
        "recordID": 2,
        ...
    },
```

It seems to give each object an index, so I assume it's trying to sort there instead of by what the object contains? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Can't reproduce locally.   Having multiple different models then collapsing still allows sortBy to sort by the model attributes.

Comment: What do you mean by "it targets the objects"?

Comment: @ Devon I would've have thought so too, I think I'm just doing something wrong along the way.
@JonasStaudenmeir I've edited the original question, hopefully that helps you see what I mean, sorry about that.

Comment: Can you post the result of `dd($collapsed);` before and after sorting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doh! Solved my own question with a simple fix after many hours of trying.

All I was missing was that the following line:

```
$records = $collapsed->all();
```

should have been:

```
$records = $collapsed->values()->all();
```

Can't believe I missed that. Thanks to those users who responded to try and help me out.